# In PySpark, how do I avoid an error when using exceptAll after a dropDuplicates (with subset)?

Tags: pyspark, drop-duplicates

I am working on a sequence of transformations in PySpark (version 3.3.1).

At certain point I have a `dropDuplicates(subset=[X])` followed by a `exceptAll`, and I get an error. Here is a reproducible pipeline:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 'a', 'AAA'), (1, 'a', 'XXX'), (2, 'b', 'BBB')],
    ['n', 'm', 'raw']
)

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 'a', 'AAA'), (2, 'b', 'BBB')],
    ['n', 'm', 'raw']
)

df1.show()
df2.show()
```

```
+---+---+---+
|  n|  m|raw|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  a|AAA|
|  1|  a|XXX|
|  2|  b|BBB|
+---+---+---+

+---+---+---+
|  n|  m|raw|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  a|AAA|
|  2|  b|BBB|
+---+---+---+
```

We `dropDuplicates` from `df1` using `subset`:

```py
df1 = df1.dropDuplicates(subset=['n', 'm'])
df1.show()
```

And we get this, as expected:

```
+---+---+---+
|  n|  m|raw|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  a|AAA|
|  2|  b|BBB|
+---+---+---+
```

Then we attempt a `exceptAll` between DataFrames:

```py
df1.exceptAll(df2).show()
```

And the error arises:

```
23/07/27 17:19:33 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 128.0 (TID 230)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't find raw#931 in [n#929L,m#930,raw#1007,sum#1005L]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$$anonfun$bindReference$1.applyOrElse(BoundAttribute.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$$anonfun$bindReference$1.applyOrElse(BoundAttribute.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:589)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:698)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:589)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:560)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:528)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$.bindReference(BoundAttribute.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.GenerateExec.boundGenerator$lzycompute(GenerateExec.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.GenerateExec.boundGenerator(GenerateExec.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.GenerateExec.$anonfun$doExecute$6(GenerateExec.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LazyIterator.results$lzycompute(GenerateExec.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LazyIterator.results(GenerateExec.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LazyIterator.hasNext(GenerateExec.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$ConcatIterator.advance(Iterator.scala:199)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$ConcatIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:227)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage6.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I expected the `exceptAll` to run correctly, in this case returning an empty DataFrame, since `df1` (after the `dropDuplicates`) is identical to `df2`.

I have noticed that the error mentions that the `raw` column could not be found (`Couldn't find raw#931 in [n#929L,m#930,raw#1007,sum#1005L]`), i.e., it looked for `raw#931` but only `raw#1007` is available (I believe the numbers are the references Spark uses to identify the columns, right?)

**Furthermore, if we remove the parameter `subset` from `dropDuplicates`, the error is not raised**.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is there a way to remove duplicates (only using a subset of columns), and use the resulting DataFrame into a `exceptAll` comparison?

Comment: I just tried adding ```df1.cache()``` just before the ```df1.exceptAll(df2).show()``` and it worked but don't know why. it would be great if someone explains it.

Comment: Hi @NivedithaS! Thanks for the comment... I have tried adding `df1.cache()` and it indeed worked! So, it seems like a viable workaround. In my real-world scenario I am not sure if caching the df in that spot of the pipeline will be possible, but it is indeed valuable information! I wonder if this is something that should be informed to the team at Spark, or if it is something about the usage that is wrong...